# AWS boto: how to get a list of all Internet gateways attached to a VPC

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

Given a VPC ID, find all gateways attached to it.

I tried to use filters, like these here, but I always get exceptions:

```
gws = conn.get_all_internet_gateways(filters={'attachments': vpc.id})
gws = conn.get_all_internet_gateways(filters={'InternetGatewayAttachment': vpc.id})
```

What's the correct filter here?

What are the filters allowed in this context?

The documentation on this topic is pretty scarce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS documentation for the [DescribeInternetGateways](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInternetGateways.html) request shows the available filters.  I think you want:

```
gws = conn.get_all_internet_gateways(filters={'attachment.vpc-id': vpc.id})
```